# how do I determine if this is latin1 or utf8?

Tags: c, character-encoding

I have a string "Artîsté" in latin1 table. I use a C mysql connector to get the string out of the table. I have character_set_connection set to utf8.

In the debugger it looks like :

```
"Art\xeest\xe9"
```

If I print the hex values with printf ("%02X", (unsigned char) a[i]); for each char I get

```
41 72 74 EE 73 74 E9
```

How do I know if it is utf8 or latin1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as yo can see in [the schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) of a UTF-8 sequence you can have 2 great possibilities:

- 1st bit = 0 (same as ascii), 1 byte per char having value <=0X7F
- 1st bit = 1 of utf-8 sequence, the sequence length is >= 2 bytes having value >= 0X80

This is iso-8859 encoding

```
41 72 74 *EE* 73 74 *E9*
```

only 2 stand alone bytes with values >= 0x80

**ADD BEWARE**

Be carefull! Even if you found a well formatted UTF-8 sequence, you cannot differentiate it from a bounch of ISO-8859 chars!

Comment: You say 2 single bytes, UTF8 can have up to 4? Would that be something like EEEE (4 bytes)?

Comment: sorry, bad choice of words, than I correct it. 1st byte EE 2nd byte E9 but one apart from the other

Answer (score 5):

`\x74\xee\x73` isn't a valid UTF-8 sequence, since UTF-8 never has a run of only 1 byte with the top bit set. So of the two, it must be Latin-1.

However, if you see bytes that are valid UTF-8 data, then it's not always possible to rule out that it might be Latin-1 that just so happens to also be valid UTF-8.

Latin-1 does have some invalid bytes (the ASCII control characters `0x00-0x1F` and the unused range `0x7f-0x9F`), so there are some UTF-8 strings that you can be sure are not Latin-1. But in my experience it's common enough to see Windows CP1252 mislabelled as Latin-1, that rejecting all those code points is fairly futile except in the case where you're converting from another charset to Latin-1, and want to be strict about what you output. CP1252 has a few unused bytes too, but not as many.